# LWC: @wire No such column 'UserRoleId' on entity 'User'

Tags: lightning-web-components, user, wire

I am getting this error when trying to do `@wire` for the current user.

I assume that this is some sort of sharing issue.

Is there a way to do something similar to `without sharing` for @wire so that I can pull the `UserRoleId` for the current user?

Comment: Basically, no. You'll need Apex for that sort of situation.

Comment: @sfdcfox That's what I thought, okay thank you.